# Java - array of object - setting index of one sets entire array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am so lost at this point.  It is probably something simple but..... I shrunk down the code.  I don't believe i removed anything relevant. Everything appears to works just fine EXCEPT one big flaw.  When i call SetWhosOnline, no matter what my index is, it seems to set the entire array.

My watch environment window before SetWhosOnline call.

```
    users[0].name = null
    users[1].name = null
    users[2].name = null
    users[3].name = null
    etc....
```

I call

```
    SetWhosOnline("john",1);
```

Im expecting to see...

```
    users[0].name = null
    users[1].name = john
    users[2].name = null
    users[3].name = null
```

Unfortunately - I'm getting is...

```
    users[0].name = john
    users[1].name = john
    users[2].name = john
    users[3].name = john
```

My hair is turning grey!  Hope someone has an answer out there for me....

CLASS 1

```
public class Login extends Activity {
public static who[] users = new who[100];
}

private static void SetWhosOnline(String user, int Index) {
      users[index].SETname(user);
}

 }
```

CLASS 2

```
public class who 
 {
private static boolean active;
private static boolean online;
private static String msg="";
private static int MsgCnt=0;
private static String name;
private static String IP;
private static Date stamp=new Date();


public void init(int index) {
      this.active = false;
      this.online = false;
      this.name = "";
      this.IP = "";
      this.stamp = new Date();
}  //USER   


public final void SETname(String value) {
    this.name = value;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All your fields in class who are static, hence all instances of class who will share the same data (i.e. have the same name, the same IP, etc.). Using static in this context does not make sense.

Comment: It's the little things. Thank you so much.. I am totally new to Java. I knew it was something stupid, but I'm getting there.. Thank you again!!!!!